# How to combine react-hooks, redux and typescript all together?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have been trying to combine React-hooks, Redux and Typescript. Every time I fix an error, a new one appears.

Can anyone see what the issue seems to be?

Right now I get the following **error** about my reducer:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): action.places is not iterable

Without typescript, this code works. So I should be missing something or doing something wrong type-wise.

```
// Types

export interface Place {
  type: string;
  geometry: Geometry;
  properties: Properties;
  id: number;
}

interface Geometry {
  type: string;
  coordinates: [number, number];
}

interface Properties {
  Id: string;
  Title: string;
  Url: string;
  ImageUrl: string;
  Bullets: boolean;
}


export const FETCH_DATA: string = "FETCH_DATA";

export interface FetchDataAction {
  type: typeof FETCH_DATA;
  places: Place[];
}

export type PlaceActionTypes = FetchDataAction;

export type AppActions = PlaceActionTypes;

// Action
// places = axios.create({baseURL}) (the API is an array of type Place[])

export const fetchPlaces = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  const response = await places.get(`places`);

  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_DATA",
    payload: response.data
  });
};

// Reducer

export const initialState: Place[] = [];

const placeReducer = (state = initialState, action: PlaceActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return [...state, ...action.places];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};



// Here is my Component

const HomePage = () => {
  const places: Place[] = useSelector((state: any) => state.places);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    places.length === 0 && dispatch(fetchPlaces());
  });

  console.log(places);

  return <div>HomePage</div>;
};
```

Comment: With typescript, what error are you actually getting ?

Comment: The only Error I have right now is the following error: 
"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): action.places is not iterable". It refers to the return of my placeReducer: case FETCH_DATA. The [(...state,) ...action.places] is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an error while using spread operator.

In your code you attempt to spread an object using the syntax intended for iterable objects. The correct syntax for object spread is `const cloneObject = {...originalObject};` which essentially iterates over the keys of the original object and copies the original's key/value pairs into a new object literal.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax)

For function calls: `myFunction(...iterableObject);`

For array literals or strings: `[...iterableObject, 'one', '2', 'three'];`

For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018): `let objectClone = { ...object }`;

So in the `reducer`, the return should be an object. If you want an array then, you can create it after you create an object

```
const placeReducer = (state = initialState, action: PlaceActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return {...state, ...action.places};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```